# block-[region].tpl.php is not working?

Tags: 6, blocks, theming

I just created the **Blocks** and **Regions** in drupal 6. Now I want to align these regions (by using DIV id's etc..), so I created a block-[region].tpl.php file and write HTML and PHP scripts. Unfortunately these scripts are not showing in that regions, only the block contents are showing.

By the [article](http://drupal.org/node/104319), template files are searched in the following order:

- block-[module]-[delta].tpl.php
- block-[module].tpl.php
- **block-[region].tpl.php**
- block.tpl.php

But the contents in the files are not displaying. How I figure-out this problem ?

Comment: Did you clear Drupal's cache after you created the new template file?

Comment: @Clive Yes I cleared cache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My best guess is that you haven't copied across the standard `block.tpl.php` file into your theme. This is required (for a reason that escapes me) for overriding node and block templates.

There's a bit of a discussion about it in the comments on the link you posted.

Comment: I am working on garland theme, and I read the discussion, but it not helped me !.

Comment: Hmmm Drupal sites all over the place seem to be behaving very weirdly today...can you just confirm the name of your region as you've defined it in the `.info` file as well as the exact name of your block template file?

Comment: Thanks it working fine, I was misspelled the name region name.

Comment: After adding the block,tpl.php to my theme folder, my custom region block templetes began to work. Thanks for the solution.